# Are the pipes in the Mario series made by Mario as tunnel entries to infiltrate Bowser's kingdom or are they a normalcy?

Tags: video-games, super-mario-brothers

Is there any link available to a manual/source concerning the pipes in Mario games? Are they made by Mario as tunnel entries to infiltrate Bowser's kingdom or were they already there and Mario is making use of them?
Mario is known to be a plumber and Bowser is not an industrialist. Most of his army is wild creatures.
⠀‎
Details such as this are frequently lost in localization. The same thing happened with Sonic's non-JP manuals. Most don't know that there was a consistent vision regarding the story since these materials weren't available in English. (e.g. Eggman always aiming to build a worldwide theme park, ancient gods being part of classic Sonic's story, etc.)

Comment: Bowser may not be an industrialist, but when you have that many turtles, you're gonna need some pipes. You know how it is.

Comment: Note that Mario initially found Mushroom Kingdom by accident, while passing through an existing pipe. That pipe existed before Mario's presence in Mushroom Kingdom.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @Machavity has already explained to you why you can't vandalize your post. I've temporarily locked your post so you can't vandalize it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to the Nintendo authorised comic [Super Mario Bros. Special Edition #1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001VT4YOC), the tunnel network of warp pipes was created by the former inhabitants of the Mushroom Kingdom, mice.

[image]

Comment: @JoaquinOld - These are warp pipes that allow instantaneous travel. Perhaps they traveled to other galaxies. Out-of-universe they developed warping abilities (via the magic of retcon) much later in the mythos. Originally they were just travel pipes.

Comment: @JoaquinOld - Like the evolution of Superman, it seems to have just happened from game to game to game

Comment: @JoaquinOld - In the earliest games there were no other galaxies. All of the action took place in a single locale. Over time they added additional depth to the back-story

Comment: As the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy explains, “These creatures you call mice you see are not quite as they appear, they are merely the protrusions into our dimension of vast, hyper-intelligent pan-dimensional beings.” So intergalactic pipes are probably well within their abilities.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I didn't know H2G2 to be part of Mushroom Kingdom's lore!

Comment: "And so, having been driven from the Mushroom Kingdom, Mouser use the power of mushrooms to have all the mice trip out and invade [Subcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._2)..."

Comment: @NKCampbell : Nintendo hasn't always embraced Zelda 3's storyline as a prequel. Since Nintendo of Japan hasn't always treat the North American's release title "A Link To The Past" as being crucial canon, or whether SMB3's Koopalings are Bowser's kids, I think they certainly haven't treated details from an outsourced American comic strip as critical canon. But truthfully, the games drive Nintendo stories, & their makers seem to have just inconsistently picked what they like to honor and what they don't care about forgetting, focused more on whatever seems to help easily make new games seem fun.

Comment: I retract my comment - I missed the detail that this comic was labeled as Super Mario 3

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, I'd upvote your comment, but right now it has 42 upvotes and I won't be the one to spoil that.

Comment: @Machavity well, Mario isn't exactly famous for caring about canon. In the games, Mouser was presented as an inhabitant of Subcon - which is indeed a "dream world", so it is pretty weird that the comics had many Subcon characters appear in the regular Mario "world". That said, some of the enemies in Super Mario 2 were "assimilated" in the main games (Shyguy, Ninji, Bob-Omb etc) - and remember that the western Super Mario Bros 2 originally wasn't even a Mario game - it was a "sprite swap" of Doki Doki Panic.

Answer (score 32):

Pipes appear in Yoshi's Island 2 ([example](https://gamingheartscollectionweb.wordpress.com/2016/09/14/classic-gaming-super-mario-world-2-yoshis-island-1995/)), where Mario is but a baby. Pipes also appear in Super Mario Galaxy (1 & 2) in galaxies that Mario is only seeing for the first time. Therefore, it wasn't Mario who created many (if any) of the pipes.

In Super Paper Mario, there is [Welderberg](https://www.mariowiki.com/Welderberg) who will create pipes for Mario for a fee: "I am the iron man of the forging of pipes! ... [I]t is my life's work to make the pipes for the transportation!" (See also [this gameplay](https://youtu.be/kerR_GmQgRo?t=119).) He clearly has an accent, which in the original Japanese was from the [Kansai region of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_region) according to the [Game Fandom wiki (in Japanese)](https://game.fandom.com/ja/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA).

It's also interesting to note the pipes in Daisy's homeland, Sarasaland (Super Mario Land, Gameboy), are different in appearance from the pipes that appear everywhere else, as they have segments. [These segmented pipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQGln.jpg) can also be seen in the manga KC Mario #1. Sarasaland is also the only place where you can find giant fists in the pipes, as [this gameplay shows](https://youtu.be/xh4iOlNbHNA?t=112).  No explanation for this has been given that I have found.

---

[Out of universe](https://reichanjapan.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/the-surprising-history-of-the-warp-pipe/), Miyamoto cites manga as his inspiration for warp pipes. (And the manga got it in turn from real life, as there are places in Japan where these giant pipes called 土管 lay abandoned. More about these pipes can be read on [Wikipedia in Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%9F%E7%AE%A1) or translated via [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%E5%9C%9F%E7%AE%A1).)

Comment: Can you add more detail about the japanese abandonded pipes?

Comment: @AzorAhai What do you want to know? Pipes like this, made of concrete or clay, are used across the globe in construction,

Comment: @AzorAhai - Well, for example the recurring [Open Lot](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Open_Lot) location in Doraemon is quite famous for the three big pipes of concrete that are always visible in the back (and are often used as hiding places, as chairs, to avoid rain etc....). Considering that such pipes are very frequent in many mangas/anime  especially in the '80(they are visible in the small abandoned lot Sakurambo camps in in Urusei Yatsura for example) I am quite sure they are something kids in Japan used to see a lot when playing.

Comment: The fact that those kid may dream that the pipes would connect to some distant magical land seems therefore quite possible. Anyway, I am looking for some manga source where the pipes did indeed connect to some other land.

Comment: @BlueSoul I haven't heard of any of those things .... hence why I asked for more detail. Never doubted that it wasn't factual ...

Comment: The Japanese article is interesting, I have in the past seen similar concrete pipes used as playground equipment (in New Zealand)  but more recently only purpose made plastic tubes are used.